# setCookie in PHP script

Tags: php, cookies

I am working with a simple PHP script that I want to set a cookie on. I do not want this page to refresh. Currently, the page is where I go to upload pictures, and the page refreshes when the upload is done causing the upload to never go through.

```
<?php  $password = "basicadminpassword";
        setcookie('password', $password, time()+60*60*24*365, '/', '.myurl.com');  ?>
        <?php
            // If password is valid let the user get access
            if (isset($_POST["password"]) && ($_POST["password"]=="$password")) {
        ?>
```

PROTECTED DATA

```
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div align="center">
        You must have a password to upload pictures.<br /><br />
        <form method="post">
        <input name="password" placeholder="ADMIN PASSWORD..." type="password" size="25" maxlength="15"><input style="display:none;" value="go" type="submit">
        </div>
        </form>

    <?php } ?>
```

After the user types in basicadminpassword we wont be asked for it again which will stop the refreshes from happening. If you know of a better way that would be great to hear also!

Comment: why not use Session?

Comment: Using a cookie to store plain-text admin password? You're going to have a bad time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're doing but you shouldn't save your password plain in a cookie. For security reasons that not a really good idea. Compare the password and save in a session weather the user is logged in or not.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['loggedOn'] = true;
```

Comment: Thanks. Right now it's only for myself to upload stuff to my server. I might be growing it into something larger and by that stage things will be different. I will look into sessions.